# utf-16 encoded email in sharepoint 2010 is possibile?

Tags: 2010, email, html, encoding

Is it possibile to send an html email encoded in utf-16 with sharepoint 2010?
My problem is that I have a message body wich can contain accented characters which on the receiving end are displayed wrong. I suppose this is because c# stores strings in utf-16 but sharepoint sends them in utf-8.

This is the code I'm using to send these emails:

```
StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();

headers.Add("to", user.Email);
headers.Add("from", "no-reply@domainname.com");
headers.Add("subject", oggetto);
headers.Add("content-type", "text/html"); 

SPUtility.SendEmail(mySite, headers, messaggio);
```

I tried also:

```
headers.Add("content-type", "text/html; charset:utf-16");
```

But in the headers of the email I get

text/html; charset:utf-16; charset=utf-8

So no luck for me.

Any idea?

Comment: don't know if there is a better solution, but you can still extract the SMTP server from the SPWebApplication object, and use the standard `System.Net.Mail.*` classes

Comment: So, if you change encoding in your mail client to utf-8, is text displayed successful? I suppose that charset specifies how it should be displayed by mail client.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using UTF-16 which seem difficult, you could replace your accented characters with the equivalent utf-8-safe numerical code. This would look like the the following:

```
string body = messageBody.Replace("à", "&#224;");
body = body.Replace("á", "&#225;");
```

This will effectively give your html-email-body the correct character encoding and would be displayed correct when viewed as a html message.

List: [HTML Codes - HTML Special Characters](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm)